# How to add -fpermissive option to kdevelop?

Tags: c++, cmake, kdevelop

How to add -fpermissive option in KDevelop IDE?

And -std=c++0x  option too

Comment: `-fpermissive` is a bad idea, better fix your code.

Comment: you are right. But I'm a newbie in c++, my main language is php. And I'm tired to "fight" with c++. It's too much new information for me. For the moment I want to just start the program, even it is not perfect. I didn't get why compiler wants me to add -fpermissive and to be honest I have no time for discovering it. In the future I will fix all such issues.

Comment: sometimes it is easier to add compiler flags rather than updating someone else's legacy code to support a modern version of gcc.

Answer (score 9):

Click **Open configuration** and add your flags to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` var.

If you want these flags to be set for anyone building your source, you can `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fpermissive -std=c++0x")` in `CMakeLists.txt`.